# What does the Stasis upgrade "Bonus Power" affect?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Does it only give you the chance of a bonus power when you use Stasis, or does it apply to all abilities?

Comment: I think we can safely assume that it's just Stasis.

Comment: @MrSmooth I assumed that it just gave Stasis a flat chance of x% (What was it, 30%?) to not trigger a cooldown. Never tried it, though, as it seemed worthless.

Answer (score 2):

It only applies to when you use stasis. If gives you a chance to not set off the cooldown counter, so you can use two skills back to back for a combo. It does not apply to any other skills though.